# UITableView не даёт прокрутить элементы до конца.

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

После перехода на **`DetailView`** элементы в таблице остаются, но прокрутить к ним не получается: http://youtube.com/watch?v=viYFRKjyOCs что делать?

Comment: у вас нижний край tableView и  верхний край tabBar'а в совпадают?

Comment: Да, более того, после нажатия кнопки обновить всё работает как должно.

Comment: У меня похожее было со скроллом пока не отключил autolayout для данной view, один из констрейнтов мешал. Попробуйте

Comment: Не помогло...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня не был объявлен метод `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. Поэтому кол-во `Section`’ов было равно нулю и iOS считала таблицу пустой.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```